# A special test function: can $\Delta \phi<0$ on the support of $\phi$?

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory

Is there a test function $\phi$ (smooth with compact support) with support in a ball of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with negative laplacian on its support:$\Delta \phi<0$ on its support?

Comment: I would presume that you can smooth out $-\|x-x_0\|^2$ at the boundary of whatever $B_r(x_0)$

Comment: You might want to refer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2507031/a-test-function-whose-laplacian-is-positive-at-the-center-of-a-ball/2507526

Comment: Calvin Khor: Thanks, but why the laplacian of the mollifier would be $<0$ on its support?

Comment: You tag people with @, otherwise they won't (usually) notice. I just happened to refresh this page after lunch. You're the one who posted the question so I don't need to type "@M.Rahmat." I didn't say it would be immediate, maybe there is some work to be done. But I presume it is possible (and I don't have time to check right now). But certainly the 1D problem looks easier and then you can maybe do the same for radial test functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this is impossible because the support of a function is a closed set. Thus if $\Delta \phi > 0$, by extreme value theorem, $\Delta \phi > c > 0$ on $\operatorname{supp} \phi$ for some constant $c$. But by continuity, this means $\Delta\phi>0$ on an open neighbourhood of the support, and therefore $\phi$ does not vanish outside its support, which is absurd.